# Best/proper way to fade-in-out changing html text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a sample website for practice and I created a function that changes the main background image of the site every x amount of seconds. Along with the changes to the background-image, I would like to change the title text that corresponds to each image. I can fade-in-out the background-image nicely, but the text cannot fade.

I'm assuming its because I am not changing the css but because I'm changing the html text directly so transition doesn't work.

Here is my function:

```
function updateImage() {
    if (pic == 1) {
        caption = "GO BEYOND EARTH";
    }
    else if (pic == 2) {
        caption = "EXPLORE NEW WORLDS";
    }
    else if (pic == 3) {
        caption = "EXPERIENCE DEEP SPACE";
    }

    $('.pic-titles').text(caption);
    $('.center').css('background-image', 'url(img/space' + pic + '.jpg');
    pic++;

    if (pic > 3) {
        pic = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

Right now the text just changes and it doesn't look that great. I want it to match the fade effect of the background image. I tried using jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut together but the outcome doesn't look too great.

Comment: If you want to fade one text into the other, the logical way to do it is to have 3 separate children, each with correct title and correct background and just fade them in/out as you please. You need to position them one over the other, using `position:absolute` and make sure the parent has enough height to display them and keep the space they require in document flow. Please note your code is completely out of context without CSS and HTML markup. You're supposed to create a [mcve] (live snippet).

Answer (score 0):

You need two things, the animate method and the queue. With this combo youll be able to fadeout the text on the first animate, change the text right at that point. And at last fadein the new text.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
var pic = 2;

function updateImage() {

  if (pic == 1) {
    caption = "GO BEYOND EARTH";
  } else if (pic == 2) {
    caption = "EXPLORE NEW WORLDS";
  } else if (pic == 3) {
    caption = "EXPERIENCE DEEP SPACE";
  }

//Animate function
  $('.pic-titles').animate({
      opacity: 0
    })
    .queue(function() {
      $(this).text(caption);
      $(this).dequeue();
    })
    .animate({
      opacity: 1
    });
    
    
  //$('.center').css('background-image', 'url(img/space' + pic + '.jpg');
  pic++;

  if (pic > 3) {
    pic = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="pic-titles">GO BEYOND EARTH</p>
<button onclick="updateImage()">PIC</button>
```